# cannot access simple controller as webService

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

While debugging I verified this js func is called:

```
var oAuthManager = {
    loginWithGoogle_OnClick: function () {
        createAjaxRequest("Register/GetAuthorizeRequestToken", {
                    'providerType': 'google'}).done(function (res) { });
//        createAjaxRequest("Register", null).done(function (res) { });
    }
};
```

and it calls:

```
function createAjaxRequest(url,data) {
    return $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data
            });
        };
```

So why cannot I get to this RegisterController's method?

```
 [HttpPost] \\tried with and without this
public void GetAuthorizeRequestToken(string providerType)
{
    var authType = (OAuthProviderTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(OAuthProviderTypes), providerType);
    mAuthorizationService.GetAuthorizeRequestToken(authType);
}
```

other controllers works fine with othe js.

I get the error:

```
POST http://localhost:8976/Register/GetAuthorizeRequestToken 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have two breakpoints:

- one in the ctor which stops OK
- second in the beginning of the webMethod. I see the thread never reaches there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elad,

I was able to reproduce your code pretty much line by line and is working. So let's analyze the issue.

You are not getting a 404 (not found, or a 403 (request denied)... You are getting a 500 error, which means the application broke somewhere.

So I would start investigating some of these points:

- Does your controller inherits from a base class? Is there an initialization step failing?
- Put a break point INSIDE your service call. Maybe VS is behaving badly and is not stopping on the Action as it should.

If you find nothing, I would also try the following to isolate the problem:

- Hitting the action with Fiddler
- Make the js call simpler to see if you can reach the action (e.g. post without data)
- Include a datatype on your ajax call (worked for me without it though)

That should be a good start, I hope it helps,

-covo